# Why doesn't ls show the group name?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ls

When I use `ls -l`, it does NOT show the group names in the listings.  Only the user names.

```
aj@host:/media/storage$ ll
total 724
drwxrwxrwx 10 root       4096 Sep 17 18:23 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root       4096 Jun 16 14:18 ..
drwxrwxr-x  5 aj         4096 Aug  8 01:22 blessed-data
drwxrwxr-x  4 git        4096 Jul 21 15:27 git-repos
drwx------  2 root      16384 Jun 16 14:33 lost+found
drwxrwsr-x  2 analyst    4096 Sep 17 18:23 projects
```

Why isn't `ls -l` showing group names, but only user names?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty).

Comment: What is the output of `alias ll`?

Comment: alias ll='ls -alG'

Comment: I see the -G flag in there, and that it is intended to suppress the group name in long output.  However, I just verified that ls -l gives the exact same output as ll, except it does not include dot files.

Comment: Since this is, in fact, two separate questions, I'm going to actually make this into two questions.  Points for this question go to DavidPostill.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Why isn't ls -l showing group names, but only user names?

You are using the following alias:

```
alias ll='ls -alG'
```

Remove `G` from your alias or use `ls -al`.

Alternative:

If you don't want to alter your aliases, and just want a one-time listing including groups, you can use `/bin/ls -al` which will bypass any `ls` alias you've defined.

---

> ```
> -G, --no-group
>     inhibit display of group information
> ```

Source [LS](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/ls.1.php)

Note:

- `-G` for `ls` on OS X is "Enable colorized output"

---

Comment: Sorry, I guess we both edited at just about the same time.  I actually tried ls -l, and it gave exactly the same output as ll.  No group names.

Comment: BUT, I just tried `alias ls`, and lo and behold--- ```alias ls='ls -G'``` !

Comment: If you don't want to alter your aliases, and just want a one-time listing including groups, try using `/bin/ls -al` which will bypass any `ls` alias you've defined.

Comment: @GusShortz  Good idea, answer updated :)

Comment: aaah! `-G` for `ls` on osx is "Enable colorized output". That's what I get for copy/pasting my osx bashrc into ubuntu :(

Comment: @JeffreyMartinez LOL ;)

Comment: this is what happens when you confuse BSD with GNU